# NullReference exception in clr.dll while unmanaged code calling managed function

Tags: c#, c++, .net

I have a managed application which calls into an unmanaged dll and the unmanaged dll also calls back into the managed application. The problem is with unmanaged dll calling back into managed code.

A few tests crash on our CI intermittently with message "The agent process was stopped while the test was running.". When a test crashes it creates a dump file. Callstack from Native debug session of the dump file tells that clr.dll threw exception when the unmanaged dll was trying to call a function in managed code. Below is the callstack, the unmanaged dll I wrote is at the bottom.

```
KERNELBASE.dll!RaiseException() Unknown
clr.dll!RaiseTheExceptionInternalOnly() Unknown
clr.dll!RaiseTheException(class Object *,int,enum CorruptionSeverity)   Unknown
clr.dll!RealCOMPlusThrow(class Object *,enum CorruptionSeverity)    Unknown
clr.dll!Thread::RaiseCrossContextException(class Exception *,class ContextTransitionFrame *)    Unknown
clr.dll!Thread::DoADCallBack(struct ADID,void (*)(void *),void *,int)   Unknown
clr.dll!UM2MDoADCallBack()  Unknown
clr.dll!UMThunkStub()   Unknown
UnManaged.dll!UnManagedClass::CallbackIntoManagedCode(bool * idle) Line 735 C++
UnManaged.dll!UnManagedClass::WhileLoopRunningInSeparateThread() Line 225   C++
```

So far my theory has been that if the unmanaged code called back into managed code after the managed object containing the callback got GCed then this could happen. I did identify a couple of race conditions that could lead to this situation. But even after fixing those race conditions, tests still crash with this callstack in the dump file.

Questions -

1. Is my theory sane?
2. What are the other possible scenarios that could lead to this callstack?

Reference code is below. This is similar to what I am doing. I haven't compiled this code, it is just to given an idea on how the unmanaged code is calling managed function.

```
// Managed.cs
public class MyClass
{
    private int UnmanagedCodeCallsMe(Int64 n, IntPtr c)
    {
        return n;
    }
    public delegate int CalledFromUnmanagedDelegate ( Int64 n, IntPtr c );
    private CalledFromUnmanagedDelegate willBeCalledFromUnmanaged = new CalledFromUnmanagedDelegate(UnmanagedCodeCallsMe);

    void StartUseOfCallback()
    {
        // Calls into unmanaged code to set callback
        UnmanagedFunctionSetCallback(willBeCalledFromUnmanaged);
    }

    // It is possible that this function never gets called
    void EndUseOfCallback ( )
    {
        UnmanagedFunctionFreeCallback(willBeCalledFromUnmanaged);
    }
}

---------------------Over to unmanaged code ----------------
// Unmanaged.cpp    
typedef int32 (*ManagedCallback)(int64, int32*);
public UnmanagedClass
{
   public:
    ManagedCallback CallManagedCode;

    void FreeRunningWhileLoop()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            // Do something
            int32 count;
            CallManagedCode(0, *count);
            // do domething
        }
    }

}
UnmanagedClass *globalObject;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) RegisterManagedFunction(ManagedCallback c)
{
    globalObject->CallManagedCode = c;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps, you did not show us the test program so it is just guessing.  The show is over when the MyClass object gets collected.  You use a global variable in your native code, so the *willBeCalledFromUnmanaged* should have corresponding lifetime.  It should be `static`.

Comment: Test your callback with C++/CLI console program. With this you debug all code.